# Discord.js Null checking not working in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I've been trying to get my discord bot working in TypeScript, but I've ran into an issue. I'm trying to do msg.reply(string), but it says "Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'." even though I just checked if it is null. Here's my current code:

```
import Discord = require("discord.js");

const client: Discord.Client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`connected as ${client.user?.tag}`);
});

client.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg == null){
        return;
    }

    msg.reply("hi");
});
```

I know I can just avoid it if I turn off strict null checking, but I'd rather keep it on.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**edit**:

Here's what the VS-Code compiler gives me:

```
app.ts:14:5 - error TS2721: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'.

14     msg.reply("hi");
       ~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.

The terminal process terminated with exit code: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Stick the code that uses `msg` in the conditional block, for example:

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg){
        msg.reply("hi");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but that didn't seem to change anything. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry about that! Could you add the full compiler output to your example please, also please ensure it is minimal and reproducible ...